# Will RCpp speed up the evaluation of basic R functions?

Tags: r, rcpp

Pardon me, but I do not know much about Rcpp, but I am trying to figure out if it would be good to learn it in order to improve a package I am writing.

I have written an R package that (is supposed to) efficiently and randomly samples uniformly from a high-dimensional, constrained space with an MCMC algorithm. It is (unfinished and) located at https://github.com/davidkane9/kmatching.

The problem is when I run a statistical test called the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic to see whether my MCMC algorithm has converged to a stationary distribution, I should get R = 1 for the statistic, but I get very high numbers, which basically tells me my sampling is bad and no one should use it. The solution is to take more samples and skip more (taking 1 out of ever 1000 instead of every 100). However this takes a lot of time. If you want some code to run, here is an example:

```
##install the package first
data(lalonde)
matchvars = c("age", "educ", "black")
k = kmatch(x = lalonde, weight.var = "treat", match.var = matchvars, n = 1000, skiplength = 1000, chains = 2, verbose = TRUE)
```

Looking at an Rprof output of this I get that `rnorm` and `%*%` are taking most of the time:

```
                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"kmatch"                  1453.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"hitandrun"               1450.18     99.79    128.80     8.86
"%*%"                      757.00     52.09    757.00    52.09
"cat"                      343.18     23.62    329.82    22.70
"rnorm"                    106.34      7.32    103.50     7.12
"mirror"                    35.26      2.43     21.84     1.50
"paste"                     14.02      0.96     14.02     0.96
"stdout"                    13.36      0.92     13.36     0.92
"runif"                     13.32      0.92     13.32     0.92
"/"                         12.82      0.88     12.82     0.88
">"                          7.42      0.51      7.42     0.51
"<"                          6.22      0.43      6.22     0.43
"-"                          5.78      0.40      5.78     0.40
"max"                        5.18      0.36      5.18     0.36
"nchar"                      5.12      0.35      5.12     0.35
"*"                          4.84      0.33      4.84     0.33
"min"                        3.94      0.27      3.94     0.27
"sum"                        3.42      0.24      3.42     0.24
"gelman.diag"                2.90      0.20      0.00     0.00
"=="                         2.86      0.20      2.86     0.20
"ncol"                       2.84      0.20      2.84     0.20
"apply"                      2.72      0.19      0.26     0.02
"+"                          2.48      0.17      2.48     0.17
"FUN"                        2.32      0.16      1.66     0.11
"^"                          2.08      0.14      2.08     0.14
":"                          1.24      0.09      1.24     0.09
"sqrt"                       0.96      0.07      0.96     0.07
"%%"                         0.90      0.06      0.90     0.06
"mean.default"               0.62      0.04      0.62     0.04
"lapply"                     0.40      0.03      0.26     0.02
"("                          0.32      0.02      0.32     0.02
"unlist"                     0.26      0.02      0.00     0.00
"array"                      0.12      0.01      0.02     0.00
"sapply"                     0.12      0.01      0.00     0.00
"matrix"                     0.06      0.00      0.02     0.00
"Null"                       0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
"print"                      0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
"unique"                     0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
"abs"                        0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"all"                        0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"aperm.default"              0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"as.matrix.mcmc"             0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"file.exists"                0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"list"                       0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"print.default"              0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"stopifnot"                  0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"unique.default"             0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"which.min"                  0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
"<Anonymous>"                0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"aperm"                      0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"as.mcmc.list"               0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"as.mcmc.list.default"       0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"data"                       0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"mcmc.list"                  0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"print.gelman.diag"          0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"quantile.default"           0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"sort"                       0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"sort.default"               0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"sort.int"                   0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"summary"                    0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
"summary.default"            0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
```

If I set verbose = F, the `cat` goes away, but then `%*%` takes about 70% of the time. I am wondering if it would be worthwhile to try to write my code in C++ and then use RCpp, or if because the functions that are taking so much time are basic functions (already written in C) it wouldn't be worth it and I'll just have to live with it or find a better algorithm.

Edit: According to Rprof, the one line that is holding me up is `u = Z %*% r` in `hitandrun`:

```
## This is the loop that is being run millions of times and taking forever
for(i in 1:(n*skiplength+discard)) {
        tmin<-0;tmax<-0;
        ## runs counts how many times tried to pick a direction, if
        ## too high fail.
        runs = 0
        while(tmin ==0 && tmax ==0) {
          ## r is a random unit vector in with basis in Z
          r <- rnorm(ncol(Z))
          r <- r/sqrt(sum(r^2))

          ## u is a unit vector in the appropriate k-plane pointing in a
          ## random direction Z %*% r is the same as in mirror
          u <- Z%*%r
          c <- y/u
          ## determine intersections of x + t*u with walls
          ## the limits on how far you can go backward and forward
          ## i.e. the maximum and minimum ratio y_i/u_i for negative and positive u.
          tmin <- max(-c[u>0]); tmax <- min(-c[u<0]);
          ## unboundedness
          if(tmin == -Inf || tmax == Inf){
            stop("problem is unbounded")
          }
          ## if stuck on boundary point
          if(tmin==0 && tmax ==0) {
            runs = runs + 1
            if(runs >= 1000) stop("hitandrun found can't find feasible direction, cannot generate points")
          }
        }

        ## chose a point on the line segment
        y <- y + (tmin + (tmax - tmin)*runif(1))*u;

        ## choose a point every 'skiplength' samples
        if(i %% skiplength == 0) {
          X[,index] <- y
          index <- index + 1
        }
        if(verbose) for(j in 1:nchar(str)) cat("\b")
        str <- paste(i)
        if(verbose) cat(str)
      }
```

it is actually the only time I do matrix multiplication in my sampling loop, however I do it thousands of times, once per sample taking a million samples and throwing out 99%.

Comment: If you could provide the source code for the bottleneck, you'll be able to get better advice, but generally R is bad at the sorts of computations MCMC requires, and C++ is good. See e.g. http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gibbs-sampler/

Comment: Re-writing matrix multiplication is not going to be faster, since it will use the same underlying BLAS.  If you want `%*%` to be faster, use an optimized BLAS.

Comment: have you thought about running your code parallel (eg. parallel package) this could help, specially when you need a huge amount of random numbers. It is also quite conman to run different chains of the MCMC algorithm parallel....

Comment: @hadley I've added some of the source code, the whole file is rather long, if I should post more, let me know.

Comment: @holzbrn yes that would be a good idea I am going to try doing that next, I just want to make sure (this is what Gelman-Rubin is testing) that the different chains are sampling reliably from the same distribution.

Comment: If you run in parallel, make sure to use a suitable RNG. It might also be faster to run `rnorm` and `runif` outside the loop and just index them inside, since it looks like you know you need at most 1000*ncol(Z) `rnorm` calls and 1000 `runif` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rcpp has in fact been used a lot for precisely this purpose: MCMC.  You generally get pretty decent speed gains on the order of 30 to 50 or 70.

One of the early packages is Whit's [rcppbugs](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rcppbugs) which he converted to Rcpp for general ease of use after having programmed it with some classes he wrote.  A casual web search for 'Rcpp MCMC' will lead you to a few posts.

And other authors have used Rcpp for this as well.  And it also sits on the inside of (R)Stan as you really want the *looping constructs inherent in MCMC* to be running as fast as possible. Hence compiled.

I asked the rcpp-devel list last week what I should talk about in a brief R User Group presentation I'll give tomorrow, and the 'MCMC' suggestions more or less dominated.  One entire talk from another RUG was presented too.  I'd link to the thread but somehow it fell of Gmane's archive for rcpp-devel.

So in sum I'd say yes, you do want to consider using Rcpp here.